# Trying to increase my joomla website speed

Tags: joomla-2.5

I have read that if you enable the plugin "System - cache", the speed of your joomla website increases a lot...
I have done it, and it's true, but some navs' css and the Slider dissapears...
Do you know why...?

Comment: It might be due to the fact that you once enabled then disable the plugin, made CSS changes to your website, and have now re-enabled it again. This will mean that you're using an older cache. To avoid doing so, simply clear your Joomla cache

Comment: I did it, but some errors didn't get fixed

Comment: Are any errors appearing on your browser console?

Comment: Yes... http://gyazo.com/819d48c9c8c486b26267534a6bbce64f

Comment: I would maybe suggest using the jQuery Easy plugin

Comment: I have done it. I have imported: //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js and //code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JCH Optimize of one of those plugins that you will have to tinker the settings for.

For me to get it working, I set the following parameters:

- Defer javascript = **Yes**
- Combine JavaScript Files - **Yes**
- Manage combined files - **Combine files in one**
- Exclude all extensions - **No**

Hopefully this will prevent any errors being thrown

Comment: I have it installed, anyway, i will try changing the configuration in the way you're telling to me.

Answer (score 0):

No, not unless you share a link to your site *or* a Codepen with a sample of the code from it.

At the very least you might want to mention the exact version of Joomla you are using, what template you have as the default and what slider extension you are using. We're not mind readers…

Comment: Web Page: http://ganeshgrow.es/ Joomla 2.5 Slider: Slideshow CK Template: Pajuh

Comment: Seth, as much as I agree with the **"we need more info"** comment, please can you post comments like this as an actual comment and not an answer ;)

Comment: @Lodder My answer to the question ‘Do you know why…?‘ was ‘No’; with some additional info to support my answer. Poor questions get poor answers.

Comment: @SethWarburton I always err on the side of poor questions getting no answers.

Answer (score 0):

From the errors it looks like the vanishing css files are ones that are generated from [less](http://lesscss.org/) or similar preprocessor and cached in the media folder by the extension ("nextend?"). The important part is that the generated cache files have automatically generated unique names that change every time the extension generates them. Which should happen whenever the settings for the extension change. The old version of the cached file is deleted and references to it return now a 404 error.

Now obviously the pages cached by the system plugin do not automatically update to use the new name, and will use the old filename and fail to load them with 404 error. The solution is to purge cache whenever you change the settings and the dynamically generated files change. I think there are extensions that add a clear cache button to the administartor to make this less annoying.